# Reading unicode files in python

Tags: python, file, unicode

Well I have a file containing unicode "û". This is however not read correctly as shown in the following test case:

```
print("û")
with open(r"testfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Which outputs:

```
û
Ã»
```

The IDE can correctly display the character - yet from reading the file another character is shown.
If I execute it in the debugger I see that `f` has as "encoding" cp1252. Not unicode.

So how would I "fix" this?

Opening the file in notepad++ tells me the file really is UTF-8. If I manually change the file to be windows-codepage 1252 it seems to work. But that's not really what I want.

Comment: Per default `open` uses the encoding returned by [`locale.getpreferredencoding`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) which basically defaults to cp1252 on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the encoding when opening the file:

```
with open(r"testfile.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.  Can I ask what version of Python you are using?  Is this a Python 3 thing?

Comment: yes I think so.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I guess I'll have to use the codecs library then.

Comment: :D Python3 is calling you...

Comment: Lol.  The newer sites that I maintain use it.  Just not the one that I am working on now.  Eventually, the day will come.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the encoding parameter as "utf-8", while opening the file.
that looks like below along with the with open().
You may want to read up on this more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

```
  encoding='utf-8'
```